# Is this possible in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to do something I am unsure is possible and need a general direction.  I have a Wordpress 3.31 multi-site set up.  I have several custom roles set up.  Student, Teacher1, Teacher2, Teacher3, Family and Friends.

I also have several custom post types set up.  The Teacher custom post type is what I am concerned with.

In the very near future we are going to have to add about 3000 blogs to this system.  I would like the name of the custom post type to be the name of the person in the teacher role for that blog - automatically. There can be up to three teachers per blog.

So I am thinking somehow query the wp_usermeta for teacher role and then display the teacher's name. in the custom post set up (below)  It would have to loop up to three times since Students may have several teachers.  Anyone out there have any idea if this is possible and a general direction?

I.E.

```
register_post_type( 'journal_teacher',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __(query-here-for-teacher-role) ),...
```

Comment: Your question will be more successful if it is in the title. Ex: How do I make dynamically named Wordpress custom post types? Additionally, the Wordpress stack exchange may be relevant to your interests. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking in turning Wordpress into a LMS system I strongly recommend you using Courseware, http://coursewa.re/. It will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have a custom post type include I use. That roughly includes something like this:

You could likely create something for the $types array that would help you accomplish what you need.

```
<?php
// ADDING CUSTOM POST TYPE
add_action('init', 'all_custom_post_types');

function all_custom_post_types() {

    $types = array(

        // Student
        array('the_type' => 'students',
          'single' => 'Student',
          'plural' => 'Students',
          'hierarchical' => true,
          'support' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
          'taxonomy' => array('') ),

       // Teacher1
       array('the_type' => 'teacher1',
          'single' => 'Teacher1',
          'plural' => 'Teachers1',
          'hierarchical' => true,
          'support' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
          'taxonomy' => array('') ),

      // Teacher2
                array('the_type' => 'teacher2',
                  'single' => 'Teacher2',
                  'plural' => 'Teachers2',
                  'hierarchical' => true,
                  'support' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
                  'taxonomy' => array('') ),

                // Teacher3
                array('the_type' => 'teacher3',
                  'single' => 'Teacher3',
                  'plural' => 'Teachers3',
                  'hierarchical' => true,
                  'support' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
                  'taxonomy' => array('') ),

                // Family and Friends - not sure if this is 2 or 1 category - but you get the idea by now.
                array('the_type' => 'family-and-friends',
                  'single' => 'Family and Friends',
                  'plural' => 'Family and Friends',
                  'hierarchical' => true,
                  'support' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
                  'taxonomy' => array('') )

        );

    foreach ($types as $type) {

        $the_type = $type['the_type'];
      $single = $type['single'];
      $plural = $type['plural'];

        $labels = array(
        'name' => _x($plural, 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x($single, 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', $single),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New '. $single),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit '.$single),
        'new_item' => __('New '.$single),
        'view_item' => __('View '.$single),
        'search_items' => __('Search '.$plural),
        'not_found' =>  __('No '.$plural.' found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No '.$plural.' found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
      );

      $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true, // $rewriter,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => $type['hierarchical'],
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => $type['support']
      );

      register_post_type($the_type, $args);

    }

}

?>
```

---

I've modified the $types array for you - if you need to adjust it hopefully you understand how to from this. If not I'll probably need more information on it.

Comment: Thanks for this...  I am not an advanced php coder, and would like to understand this.  If I 'grab' the teacher id associated with the blog in $types using function get_users/get_user_meta then I can use that variable in my labels array for custom post type teacher?  Thanks for any additional diretion...

Comment: That definitely puts me in the right direction - now I just have to do it by Blog id with the name of the teacher in the teacher role - thanks for the head start;-)  Not sure how to do that yet - but will play around and see where I get - thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Mike: user10660 [tried to amend your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/236556) -- some of the content looks useful, but I don't know this nearly as well as you do. Do with it what you will. (Doing nothing is fine by me.)